# Next.js localstorage value always return false

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage

I'm trying to check is localStorage value is correct.
Localstorage value is successfully saved.
I wonder why it always return false.

```
console.log('isTrue',localStorage.getItem('third') == "2") // false
console.log('value',localStorage.getItem('third'))  // "2"
localStorage.setItem('third', JSON.stringify(third)) // save like this
```

[image]

[image]

Can someone help what is wrong?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Check the API spec for local storage and the get/set methods, particularly the return type of `.getItem` - you'll need to `JSON.parse` the store value before doing comparisons between other data or doing other work with it, i.e.

```
console.log('isTrue', JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('third')) === "2") --> true
```